# Javascript function onclick of two objects

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I am curios to know if something like these would work in javascript, or if there is a way to do it. Basically, i want to call a function onclick of one object and the same function onmouseover of another object.

```
document.getElementById("one").onmouseover || document.getElementById("two").onclick= function() {myFunction()};
```

is this possible

Comment: As Quentin said: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/L0d7es97/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign a value to something, the expression evaluates as that value.

```
foo = bar = 1;
```

Your code would be clearer if you just used named functions though.

```
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("mouseover", myFunction);
document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click",     myFunction);
```